# What is probability that equation $x^2+px+q=0$ has both positive solutions?

Tags: probability

Given: $|p|\le1$ and $|q|\le1$. Please help me to find it.

Comment: You said nothing about $p$ and $q$: are they random variables? What is their distribution? Are they independent?

Comment: Given: |p|≤1 and |q|≤1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p$ and $q$ are independently uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$, we want to find the area portion of the square$[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ that leads to positive roots.

Note that the roots are real iff $p^2\ge4q$. Once we know that, the real roots have the same sign iff $q>0$. And after that, the common sign is positive iff $p<0$ (Vieta). Use this to make a sketch of the region we are interested in and find its area by a suitable integral.